# Datetime object with timezone

Tags: python, datetime

How do I get an aware datetime object using the modified timestamp from a file? I've done it this way:

```
modified = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(myfile))
isotime = modified.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z')
```

but this just gets me a naive time, so %z is a blank string like: 2016-09-03 10:35:24

I've been using this documentation, but I can't understand how to make a tzinfo object for the system timezone: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pain in the ass to get the current time zone using python standart library.

Just install [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html) package:

```
$ sudo pip install python-dateutil
```

and you can do the following:

--

```
>>> from dateutil.tz import tzlocal
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime("file"), tz=tzlocal())
```